# Insert query with special characters in sqlite and get that data back SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

**Insert Query:**

```
Insert into NEWS(NewsID,NewsHeading,NewsDescription,NewsLink)
values (106339025,Giuliani associate Parnas says Trump'knew exactly what was going on',The indicted associate of President Trump's personal lawyer Rudy Giuliani said in an interview that Trump "knew exactly what was going on," NBC News reports.,https://www.cnbc.com/2020/01/15/giuliani-associate-parnas-says-trump-knew-exactly-what-was-going-on.html)
```

**Question:** How to insert query with special characters in SQLite and get that data back in string format? As when I am inserting the data it shows error.

I am getting the string with special characters

When I converted the string in utf8CString i am getting the following result.

`[66, 101, 105, 106, 105, 110, 103, 32, 99, 114, 97, 99, 107, 105, 110, 103, 32, 100, 111, 119, 110, 32, 111, 110, 32, 73, 80, 32, 116, 104, 101, 102, 116, 32, 99, 111, 117, 108, 100, 32, 98, 111, 111, 115, 116, 32, 105, 110, 118, 101, 115, 116, 109, 101, 110, 116, 32, 105, 110, 32, 67, 104, 105, 110, 97, 44, 32, 102, 111, 114, 109, 101, 114, 32, 85, 83, 32, 110, 101, 103, 111, 116, 105, 97, 116, 111, 114, 32, 115, 97, 121, 115, 0]`

But i am unable to get it back to the string

I converted the string into `utf8CString` but when I am fetching the data it's not converting back to string.

Can someone please explain to me how to insert query.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or SQLite?

Comment: I am using SQLite and swift 5

Comment: So whats the error?

Comment: I am unable to decode it again to string which I want

Comment: When I converted the string in `utf8CString` i am getting the following result.   `[66, 101, 105, 106, 105, 110, 103, 32, 99, 114, 97, 99, 107, 105, 110, 103, 32, 100, 111, 119, 110, 32, 111, 110, 32, 73, 80, 32, 116, 104, 101, 102, 116, 32, 99, 111, 117, 108, 100, 32, 98, 111, 111, 115, 116, 32, 105, 110, 118, 101, 115, 116, 109, 101, 110, 116, 32, 105, 110, 32, 67, 104, 105, 110, 97, 44, 32, 102, 111, 114, 109, 101, 114, 32, 85, 83, 32, 110, 101, 103, 111, 116, 105, 97, 116, 111, 114, 32, 115, 97, 121, 115, 0]`
But i am unable to get it back to the string

Comment: Since you're using SQLite, you can remove the <mysql> and <sql-server> tags.

Comment: Done @DaleK. Question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `String` Extension.

```
extension String {
    func base64Encoded() -> String? {
        return data(using: .utf8)?.base64EncodedString()
    }

    func base64Decoded() -> String? {
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: self) else { return nil }
        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    }
}
```

**Try this!!**
Just encode the string in base64 and save it in the database and decode it when retrieving it from the database.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use string value inside of ''(single quotes).

Use \ before single quotes, if the single quotes inside of value like `'Giuliani associate Parnas says Trump\'knew exactly what was going on\''`

Try the below query. It's working for you.

```
Insert into NEWS(NewsID,NewsHeading,NewsDescription,NewsLink) 
values (106339025,'Giuliani associate Parnas says Trump\'knew exactly what was going on\'','The indicted associate of President Trump\'s personal lawyer Rudy Giuliani said in an interview that Trump "knew exactly what was going on," NBC News reports.','https://www.cnbc.com/2020/01/15/giuliani-associate-parnas-says-trump-knew-exactly-what-was-going-on.html')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am also getting other special characters like ', : and with that I am getting the error

Comment: Other special character use as it is, only use `\\` before single quotes inside of value. Please copy the query and run, then check the value in the table. You can see the value with spacial character.

Comment: how I add '\' to every special character in string as there are many special characters. Any ides?